# PyDev breaking at built-in breakpoint

Tags: python, python-3.x, eclipse, pydev

PyDev is breaking at the built-in breakpoint in Python code with the following error.

```
warning: Debugger speedups using cython not found. Run '"/Users/Work/opt/anaconda3/envs/ch_dev37/bin/python" "/Applications/Eclipse.app/Contents/Eclipse/plugins/org.python.pydev.core_8.0.1.202011071328/pysrc/setup_cython.py" build_ext --inplace' to build.
Could not connect to 127.0.0.1: 5678
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/Eclipse.app/Contents/Eclipse/plugins/org.python.pydev.core_8.0.1.202011071328/pysrc/_pydevd_bundle/pydevd_comm.py", line 462, in start_client
    s.connect((host, port))
ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 61] Connection refused
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Volumes/GoogleDrive/My Drive/free_energy_data/write_energies.py", line 111, in <module>
    write_gases, write_adsorbates, verbose)
  File "/Users/Work/opt/dev/gits/CatHub/cathub/catmap_interface.py", line 31, in write_energies
    breakpoint()
  File "/Applications/Eclipse.app/Contents/Eclipse/plugins/org.python.pydev.core_8.0.1.202011071328/pysrc/pydev_sitecustomize/sitecustomize.py", line 74, in custom_sitecustomize_breakpointhook
    pydevd.settrace(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Applications/Eclipse.app/Contents/Eclipse/plugins/org.python.pydev.core_8.0.1.202011071328/pysrc/pydevd.py", line 2623, in settrace
    notify_stdin=notify_stdin,
  File "/Applications/Eclipse.app/Contents/Eclipse/plugins/org.python.pydev.core_8.0.1.202011071328/pysrc/pydevd.py", line 2688, in _locked_settrace
    py_db.connect(host, port)  # Note: connect can raise error.
  File "/Applications/Eclipse.app/Contents/Eclipse/plugins/org.python.pydev.core_8.0.1.202011071328/pysrc/pydevd.py", line 1262, in connect
    s = start_client(host, port)
  File "/Applications/Eclipse.app/Contents/Eclipse/plugins/org.python.pydev.core_8.0.1.202011071328/pysrc/_pydevd_bundle/pydevd_comm.py", line 462, in start_client
    s.connect((host, port))
ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 61] Connection refused
```

I am running the Python code using the 'Run' option (Play button in the attached image) in GUI.

[image]

This behavior is surprising because as the [release notes](https://www.pydev.org/history_pydev.html) says breakpoint() builtin has been supported since earlier release (**v6.5.0**) of PyDev. So far I have used `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()` for a breakpoint and it is still functioning well. The breakpoint() builtin is working well without any problem outside PyDev in a terminal.

**Additional Details:**

```
Python Version: 3.7.8
Eclipse Version: 2020-09 (4.17.0)
PyDev Version: 8.0.1
Device: MacBook Pro
OS: macOS Big Sur 11.0.1
```

Comment: Did you try and `run '"/Users/Work/opt/anaconda3/envs/ch_dev37/bin/python" "/Applications/Eclipse.app/Contents/Eclipse/plugins/org.python.pydev.core_8.0.0.202009061309/pysrc/setup_cython.py" build_ext --inplace' to build`?

Comment: Not sure if I understand you correctly. Just updated the post about how I run the code. I simply use the 'Python Run' option using the 'Run' button (Play button in GUI).

Comment: Okay so your answer is no. The error is telling you exactly what command you have to run in the terminal/command line in order to fix that issue. So I'd try that and then see if the issue is still there.

Comment: When I run using the eclipse gui ('play' button), the python interpreter used is indeed "/Users/Work/opt/anaconda3/envs/ch_dev37/bin/python". I use the IDE to run the scripts using the GUI and don't use it in a mode where I enter commands to execute the scripts.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, `breakpoint()` tries to connect to the IDE using the `Remote Debugger`, and, the `ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 61] Connection refused` means that you haven't started the remote debugger in the client side.

So, to fix this, please start the debug server in the client side prior to the run (then on launch it will run without the debugger attached until `breakpoint()` is reached).

See: https://www.pydev.org/manual_adv_remote_debugger.html for info on how to start the remote debugger on the client side.

Comment: Thank you! When I run the code after starting the debug server, the code is now executed until the breakpoint() and prints `Debug Server at port: 5678` to the console. The control is not returned to the user nor I could continue the execution. How can I avail the interactive features as possible with using `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()` within PyDev? Or is this a limitation?

Comment: At that point you should be able to use the debugger from the IDE... why are you looking to use pdb instead of the actual PyDev debugger in this case?